# Is there a way to add a dictionary to Sublime text and enable predictive typing using it?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want the editor to suggest words to me as I type. It does this currently to the words that are already present in the editor. But I want it to suggest from a standard dictionary.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: First go to this page https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html if not then try this one
Try this one https://packagecontrol.io/packages/All%20Autocomplete

Comment: @Akshay Kathpal - This is a good answer to the question IMO. Consider making it a real answer rather than a comment. You will need to expand on what the package does and how it answers the question  to get around the link-only answer but I think you can do that and get some credit for your good knowledge.

Comment: @AkshayKathpal the first link you mentioned is only for HTML files and in the case of the second one, it only suggests words from the other open files in the window. I can have a list of all English words open in the window using this as a work around but I was looking at a simpler solution, if there was one.

Comment: @jwpfox I have written the answer. Check it out

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [completions file](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html). Just insert all words you want to complete into the completions list. Select *Preferences > Browse Packages...* and open the folder `User`, there you create a file with the extension `.sublime-completions`, e.g. `MyWords.sublime-completions` with the content:

```js
{
    "scope": "text",  // <- your language scope here, press ctrl+alt+shift+p

    "completions":
    [
        "hello",
        "world",
        "foo",
        "bar",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about the Sublime text editor but Atom supports this functionality.
You can download the atom from [here](https://atom.io/).

BTW Atom is free of cost rather than sublime. Both have same functionality. But to execute program you can use command line to execute.

Here is the link for Atom https://atom.io/

and here is the link for the autocomplete package for English : https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-en-en

Hope this may helps you.

Go through the images provided in the Second link.

Comment: The OP asked for help with sublime, not for general advice on the text editors. Also, `Both have same functionality.` is obviously not true.